# Aligning Decimal Values with Blank Space String?

Tags: javascript, alignment, decimal, padding

I am having trouble adding blank spaces to align the decimals. I understand the logic but I can't put it into code.

```
for(var j in totals_array)
        {
            var amount = format_numeric_with_commas(totals_array[j].amount);
            var currency = totals_array[j].currency;
            if(j < 1)
            {
                costs_total.push(currency + " " + amount + "\x0A");
            }
            else
                costs_total.push(currency + Array(0).join(" ") + amount + "\x0A");
        }
```

`totals_array` holds a number of objects which looks like this.

```
{"currency":"AUD","amount":210543}
```

`format_numeric_with_commas` gives me the amount value in the appropriate format which is stored into the variable `amount`. While `currency` takes the currency of the value, i.e. GBP, USD, etc. What the if statement is for checks if it's the first index in the array. As I already sort the values with the highest at the top. So what I want is for the other values to align with the top number's decimal.

I take the currency type and value and push into a new array called `costs_total`. This is what it currently looks like.

Current layout:

[image: Current layout]

How would I go about doing a loop to check how many spaces are needed for different lengths of currency values?

Comment: @kukkuz are you able to help?

Comment: the easiest thing to do I guess would be to have a two-column layout... so that you can `text-align: right` for the "amount"s and it will align as desired... Well, if that isn't what you are looking for, can you put a snippet so that we can play with the code? Thanks!

Comment: @kukkuz I'd prefer to do it this way. If I was also to do that then the currencies would not be aligned depending on the length of the value.

Comment: cool... could you please give us a fiddle / snippet with the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this instead?  (some examples with actual text / numbers)

```
costs_total.push(String.Format("{0} {1,12:N}\x0A", "USD", 123456.0)); 
// "USD   123,456.00\n"

costs_total.push(String.Format("{0} {1,12:N}\x0A", "AUD", 123.0));    
// "AUD       123.00\n"

costs_total.push(String.Format("{0} {1,12:N}\x0A", currency, amount));
```

You'd just need to find the number of digits in the largest number and set the width (12 in this case) appropriately.